# MailMessage encoding on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs

I have some fairly simple code to send an email with Unicode characters in the body. When I run this in a normal MVC app there is no problem. But when running from within a WebJob the encoding is lost and the body becomes gibberish. It doesn't matter if I run the WebJob locally or deployed, same result.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.From = new MailAddress(from);            
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));

message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = "ὠμέγα";
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Ok. I worked it out. The message body being passed to the WebJob in a string was wrongly encoded.